# how to create a new database in sqlite? we have to use sqlite because we are making an android application.

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am new to sqlite. I am making an android app. on server side I want a database in sqlite. but unable to create own database on it.

```
sqlite> mydb.db;
```

OR

```
sqlite> sqlite3 mydb.db;
```

OR

```
sqlite> $sqlite3 mydb.db;

Error: near "mydb": syntax error

sqlite> $ sqlite3 mydb.db;

Error: unrecognized token: "$"
```

I had tried all the above commands but it gives error.
please guide me what is the correct command.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

All this is copy paste from the first like on a google search. Now spot the differences and it will work :)

```
For example, to create a new SQLite database named "ex1" with a single table named "tbl1", you might do this:

$ sqlite3 ex1
SQLite version 3.8.4 2014-02-11 16:24:34
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> create table tbl1(one varchar(10), two smallint);
sqlite> insert into tbl1 values('hello!',10);
sqlite> insert into tbl1 values('goodbye', 20);
sqlite> select * from tbl1;
hello!|10
goodbye|20
sqlite>


sqlite> CREATE TABLE tbl2 (
   ...>   f1 varchar(30) primary key,
   ...>   f2 text,
   ...>   f3 real
   ...> );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! i think i am using a wrong console. instead of $ in my console there is sqlite>. when i try to run commands here it give me error. kindly help me in choosing the right console.

Answer (score 0):

You should run this `sqlite3 mydb.db` command from bash or any other shell not from sqlite console. And you can check the result in sqlite console with `.databases` command:

Here is my output:

```
laptop@~$ sqlite3 mydb.db
SQLite version 3.7.17 2013-05-20 00:56:22
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .databases
seq  name             file                                                      
---  ---------------  ----------------------------------------------------------
0    main             /home/nyitrai/mydb.db                                     
sqlite>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! i am working on windows 8. bash is on linux......... where i run this command on windows?????/ i had run it on windows console but it gives error of unrecognized as internal or external command:(

Comment: It's no problem. You should [open command prompt](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/commandlinereference/f/open-command-prompt.htm) and execute this command from there.

Comment: C:\> sqlite3 mydb.db                                                                 'sqqlite3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,         operable program or batch file.                                            I am getting this error when i run command on windows console.                Thanks!

Comment: OK. You should add SQLITE3.EXE to your PATH environment variable.
Here some link 
[what PATH environment variable is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) and [how can you add some new path](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.xml).

Comment: one more problem... sorry for disturbing you again and again..... i have created a database and make some tables and inserts rows in it. it was successful. but when i close the console and again open it nothing was saved :( should i have to change some permissions????

Comment: It should have created the mydb.db file where you running the sqlite3 command. Actually you were at C:\ as I see on your comment. So your file should have created at C:\mydb.db.
[How does accepting an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)